# SVG image xlink:href ignoring page code and styling

Tags: angularjs, html, svg, ionic-framework, xlink

When the xlink:href is clicked, it links to the correct page but it ignores the code that it was supposed to run, and the css styling of that page.

Background Info: Coding on a mobile app with ionic framework.

Codes to display SVG on HTML Page.

```
<object id="svgImage" type="image/svg+xml" data="img/Floor Plan SVG.svg">
                Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

Codes in .svg file

```
<a
     xlink:href="../templates/QRCode.html"
     transform= (removed to ease viewing)
     id= (removed to ease viewing)
     target="_blank">
    <path
       style= (removed to ease viewing)
       d= (removed to ease viewing)
       id= (removed to ease viewing)
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </a>
  <a
     transform= (removed to ease viewing)
     id= (removed to ease viewing)
     target="_blank"
     xlink:href="../templates/RoomInformation.html">
    <path
       style= (removed to ease viewing)
       d= (removed to ease viewing)
       id= (removed to ease viewing)
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </a>
```

Comment: Your title is somehow misleading : you are not talking about SVGImage `<image>` right ? When you talk about the "*css styling of that page*", you are talking about the one defined in the target html (i.e `QRCode.html` and `RoomInformation.html`) right ? How are you defining their CSS (in the doc or from an external styleheet) ? What happens when you set your `<object>`'s `data` directly to these pages ?

Comment: That's weird... I was able to repro on chrome, until I set an absolute path to the external stylesheet declared in the targeted html. Now, even the relative path with HTTP cache disabled does work... So, try to set an absolute path if you didn't yet.

Comment: The css is defined in the docs.  not from an external stylesheet. Also the codes for that page isnt working too..
Also, as i am deploying the program as a mobile app, absolute path could not be used.
Sorry for the late reply. @Kaiido